# Raspbian Jessie PIXEL Doesn't Start

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-jessie, pixel

I have just received a new Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. I hooked it up, turned it on and I got a "Welcome to PIXEL" that hangs on "Starting NTP server" screen (I'm pretty sure pixel is the Raspbian GUI). Then after that happens, the welcome screen stays up, but it starts a command line. Does anyone know how to fix this?[image: Picture Of it]

Comment: This is strange, and it is not the way it should look. What do you have on your SD-card? Can you enter text at the prompt? Did you try to run the command `startx`? If so, what happened?

Comment: @Bex Sorry for getting back so late. I can type, and startx works. It has Raspbian Jesse (latest) version installed.

Comment: @averysumner is accepting or allowing you to typing ?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason X doesn't seem to start automatically. If this happens, try typing `startx` to start the graphical user environment.